# Handsontable - load data to cells from MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I try to load data into Spreadsheet Handsontable from MySQL.

When I try to set data into sheet from array:

```
var objectData = [
    {liefer: 1450, beleg: 'Test String 1', dichte: '830,4'},
    {liefer: 1810, beleg: 'Test String 2', dichte: '830,7'},
    {liefer: 1204, beleg: 'Test String 3', dichte: '840,8'},
]

var container1 = document.getElementById('example1'), hot1;
hot1 = new Handsontable(container1, {
    data: objectData,
    minSpareRows: 0,
    colHeaders: [ 'Lieferschein', 'Beleg Nr', 'Dichte' ],
    columns: [
        { data: 'liefer', readOnly: true },
        { data: 'beleg', readOnly: true },
        { data: 'dichte', readOnly: true },
    ],
});
```

This example works fine.

Now I try to load data from MySQL:

**PHP:**

```
$q = mysql_query('SELECT * from table');
while($item = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
     $arr[] = array('liefer'=>$item[0], 'beleg'=>$item[1], 'dichte'=>$item[2]);
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var container1 = document.getElementById('example1'), hot1;
hot1 = new Handsontable(container1, {
    minSpareRows: 0,
    colHeaders: [ 'Lieferschein', 'Beleg Nr', 'Dichte' ],
    columns: [
        { data: 'liefer', readOnly: true },
        { data: 'beleg', readOnly: true },
        { data: 'dichte', readOnly: true },
    ],
});

$.ajax({
   url: 'content/ajax.php',
   type: 'GET',
   data: { param: 'getDataSheet' },
   success: function(data){
        var data = JSON.parse(data);
        hot1.loadData(data.data);
   }
});
```

I can't load this data. How to do this?

Sorry for my english.

Comment: can you dump the data you send to Handsontable?